# In Node JS, what is the difference between Require Express and HTTP together and separately

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is probably a very basic question.

But what is the difference between these two code snippets:

```
const express = require ('express');
const http = require ('http');
```

And

```
const express = require ('express'),
       http = require ('http');
```

Comment: There's no difference at all.

Comment: Absolutely nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no difference. The [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) state that you can initialize one or more variables with comma separation.

```
const name1 = value1 [, name2 = value2 [, ... [, nameN = valueN]]];
```